# Nodejs Socket.io is not connecting

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I'm connecting Socket in my App but the configuration is mismatched because of which socket is not connecting. What could be the problem? I'm referring to "Mastering Web Application Development with Express" for structuring

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var morgan = require('morgan'); //HTTP request logger middleware for node.js
var flash = require('connect-flash');
var multiparty = require('connect-multiparty');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var cookieSession = require('express-session');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser'); //Node.js body parsing middleware
var methodOverride = require('method-override');
var errorHandler = require('errorhandler');
var config = require('./config.js');
var passport = require('passport');
var fs = require('fs');
var sessionStore = new cookieSession.MemoryStore();
var http = require('http');
var server = http.createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');

morgan.token('id', function getId(req) {return req.id })

var accessLogStream = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/log/systemAccessWithToken.log', {flags: 'a'})

app.use(assignId)
app.use(morgan(':id :method :url :response-time', {stream: accessLogStream}))

function assignId(req, res, next) {
    next()
}

app.use(bodyParser.json()); //middleware that only parses json

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

app.use(methodOverride(function(req, res) {
    if (req.body && typeof req.body === 'object' && '_method' in req.body) {
        var method = req.body._method;
        delete req.body._method;
        return method;
    }
}));

app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(cookieSession({
    store: sessionStore,
    secret: config.sessionSecret,
    cookie: {maxAge: config.sessionMaxAge}
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session()); // persistent login sessions
app.use(flash());

if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
    app.use(errorHandler());
}
app.all('*', function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST');
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
    next();
});

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

require('./app/passport')(passport); // pass passport for configuration
var socketcon = require('./app/mainSocket.js');
socketcon.socketconfig(app, io, sessionStore, cookieParser);

require('./routes/controller.js')(app, passport); // load our routes and pass

server.listen(config.port);
```

**mainSocket.js**

```
var modules = require('../externalModules.js');
var dbConnection = modules.dbConnection;
var cryptography = modules.cryptography;

var onlineUsers = {};
var onlineUsersSocketid = {};

exports.socketconfig = function(app, io, sessionStore, cookieParser) {
    io.set('authorization', function(data, callback) {
        if (!data.headers.cookie) {
            return callback('No cookie transmitted.', false);
        }

        cookieParser(data, {}, function(parseErr) {
            if (parseErr) {
                return callback('Error parsing cookies.', false);
            }

            var sidCookie = (data.secureCookies && data.secureCookies['myuser.sid']) || (data.signedCookies && data.signedCookies['myuser.sid']) || (data.cookies && data.cookies['myuser.sid']);

            sessionStore.load(sidCookie, function(err, session) {
                if (err || !session || !session.passport.user) {
                    callback('socket Not logged in.', false);
                } else {
                    data.session = session;
                    socketSession = session;
                    console.log("socketSession value " + JSON.stringify(socketSession));
                    callback(null, true);
                }
            });
        });
    });


    io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
        console.log("socket connected");
        console.log("socket.id " + socket.id);

        socket.encryptedUserid = socketSession.passport.user.userId;
        var devicetype = "web";

        var secUserSalt = socketSession.passport.user.salt;

        socket.userid = cryptography.crypto.fnDecryption(
            socket.encryptedUserid, secUserSalt);

        var isMobile = socketSession.passport.user.isMobile;

        var devicetype = "web";
        if (isMobile) {
            devicetype = "mobile";
        }
        socket.on('user:join', function() {
            //==============================develpoment(Aug21)====================

            if (socket.userid in onlineUsersSocketid) {
                onlineUsersSocketid[socket.userid].sockets_ids
                    .push(socket.id);
                onlineUsersSocketid[socket.userid].devicetype
                    .push(devicetype);
            } else {
                onlineUsersSocketid[socket.userid] = {
                    "sockets_ids": [socket.id], // array for all sockets id of this user
                    "devicetype": [devicetype]
                }

            }
            console.log("onlineUsersSocketid " + JSON.stringify(onlineUsersSocketid));
        });

        socket.on('disconnect', function() {
            delete onlineUsersSocketid[socket.userid];
        });
    });
} // end of export module
```

What could be the issue?

Comment: how does your client code look like?

Answer (score 0):

Per the [socket.io docs](http://socket.io/docs/), these are two server-side initialization sequences that should work:

```
var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
server.listen(80);
```

or

```
var app = require('express').createServer();
var io = require('socket.io')(app);
app.listen(80);
```

You don't have either of these.

Comment: that i have 'var server = http.createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);server.listen(config.port);'